# JSF h link takes last item in list instead of current

Tags: jsf

I got a list of objects displayed in a page.
This is the view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable var="o" value="#{opleidingController.opleidingen}" border="0" >
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Code</f:facet>
            <h:link value="#{o.opl_code}" outcome="#{opleidingController.getOpleidingByCode(o.opl_code)}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Titel</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.opl_titel} "></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Thema</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.opl_thema} "></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This displays everything very well.
Like you can see I got the code part of the object set as a link.
With this code I get an object out of the database, from which I display the details.

The problem here is that every link displays the details of the last object of the list instead of the current object where I click the link.

This is the function I call (which works):

```
public String getOpleidingByCode(String code) {
    this.opleiding = this.opleidingFacade.getOpleidingByCode(code);
    return "details";
}
```

I hope any of this makes any sense?

Sorry if the solution is super clear but I am new to all of this.

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards
Deflandrex

EDIT: 
This is the function that I use to call the first view (from which I provided the code)

```
public String getOpleidingenOpThema() {
    this.opleidingen = this.opleidingFacade.getOpleidingenOpThema();
    return "resultaat";
}
```

Both the functions are located in 1 controller.

Answer (score 2):

**What happens with the current code :**

The outcome value is processed for each link element in the datatable sequentially by calling the `opleidingController.  getOpleidingByCode(o.opl_code)`. The backing bean method sets the `this.opleiding` value corresponding to the `o.opl_code`. Once all the links's `outcome` values are processed `this.opleiding` holds the value of the last `o.opl_code`. Hence, you are seeing last value from the list in the details page.

**One Proposed solution:**

The `this.opleiding` value should be set in the controller based on the `o.opl_code` when you process the details after clicking the link and not when the link is displayed and the  outcome is set. You need to

1. Set `outcome="details"` in the `h:link` tag as this value is static and does not change based on any logic in the backing bean and remove method binding.
2. Pass the value of `o.opl_code` as a request parameter to the link as given below within the h:link tag.

   `<f:param name="opl_code" value="#{o.opl_code}"/>`
3. Have the detail backing bean load the `this.opleiding` value based on the request parameter opl_code. This way you will have details for specific `opl_code` based on what link you click.

Comment: I would rather change the 3th step to something like: `Have the Detail managed bean load the opl based in the given request parameter`.

Comment: Modified the step as suggested. Thank you

Comment: Hey OTM, thanks for your reply.
I understand what is wrong. Thank you for the clear explanation.
I also understand step 1 and 2 of the problem but I'm stuck on knowledge about how to perform step 3.
They taught me always to call a page trough the controller.

Comment: Yeah,  using h:commandlink would be good. You could use the action attribute of that  to bind to a backing bean method and do the step 3 in that method and return the page.

Comment: Hey OTM
h:commandLink fixed the problem :)
Thanks for clarification and advice!